# Transacted camel route with auto-startup set to false

Tags: apache-camel

I am in the process of developing a message router which has a bunch of routes that are started and stopped at runtime based some certain conditions.

By default all these routes are configured with `auto-starup=false`

Now I am trying to add transactional support to these routes and it seems that you cannot define a transacted route and control the its startup behavior at the same time. This is because `RouteDefinition.transacted()` returns a `TransactedDefinition` instance which does not have an `autoStartup(boolean autoStartup)` method.

I am sure I am not the only one to need this kind of functionality and just wondering what is the camel way of addressing such requirements.

Thank you in advance for your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just set `autoStartup` first, eg

```
from("direct:start").autoStartup(false)
    .transacted()
    .to("mock:result");
```

Comment: Thanks Claus.
I was just trying to follow the camel in action note which stats "must".

NOTE When using transacted() in the Java DSL, you must add it right after from() to ensure that the route is properly configured to use transactions.
This isn’t enforced in the DSL because the DSL is loosely defined to
make it easy to maintain and develop Camel. There are a few tradeoffs such as this."

I'll test it works today and will accept your answer

Comment: Ah yeah you can do .routeId .autoStartup and those similiar ones first. We will update this sentence for the 2nd ed of the book to explain this better - eg transaction should come before any routing, such as .to etc. Also before .onException etc.